# Android connectedAndroidTest: NO tests found

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing

Android connectedAndroidTest: NO tests found

```
gradle :aar-lib:connectedAndroidTest

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.
FAILED  No tests found. This usually means that your test classes 
are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't 
inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
    ....
    }
}
```

Looked at the test APK, it contains the test class.

Comment: Just a few initial things to check: Are you running these from the `androidTest` folder? Have you tried clearing your run configurations for Android Instrumented Tests? (`Run > Edit Configurations...`)? Are any other test classes working?

Comment: Run it from command line, not inside android studio. Run it from root project folder - gradle :aar-lib:connectedAndroidTest.  None of the tests are recognized. The test folder name is test, androidTest points to the test folder via sourceSets { androidTest.srcDirs=['src/test/java'] }. Test is shared by Java SE project.

Comment: Interesting, though I've never tried to combine into a single test folder before now. Out of interest, do these tests work fine if you do create an `androidTest` folder, comment out `androidTest.srcDirs` and copy your test there? And do you have `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` defined in `build.gradle`?